# How to Update dashboard UI from Background Services in Blazor wasm

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I am a beginner to blazor wasm and breaking my head to find a way to update my Dashboard page ( Which is inside Blazor.Client project) from my Background Service (IHosteadService - which is in my Blazor.Server project).

Basically, I am looking for an event callback from the background service to my dashboard UI.

using .NET5 blazor Wasm ( asp.net core hosted)

my bg service code:

```
internal class MessageConsumer: BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<MessageConsumer> _log;
    private readonly IConsumer<string, int> _consumer;

    public MessageConsumer(ILogger<MessageConsumer> log, IConsumer<string, int> consumer)
    {
        _log = log;
        _consumer = consumer;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        
        var i = 0;
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var consumeResult = _consumer.Consume(stoppingToken);
            
            _log.LogInformation(consumeResult.Message.Key + " - " + consumeResult.Message.Value);

      /** Here I want to NOTIFY my dashboard UI ***/

            
            if (i++ % 1000 == 0)
            {
                _consumer.Commit();
            }
        }
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        _consumer.Dispose();
        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: Did you try 2 way binding? update the Entity class (shared project) from the background class and bind the same in the client dashboard. I am not sure but u can give a try.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "direct" way for your Blazor.server project with its BackgroundService to communicate with the Blazor.client Webassembly app. The communication has to happen by using a protocol such as HTTP or Websockets. For your case I would suggest SignalR because it enables realtime communication. Over websockets all subscribing clients get notified. [Link to SignalR Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)

Comment: Yes, I used signalR to fix this. Thanks much